# Binding to an array in Xamarin/XAML (implementing breadcrumbs)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, breadcrumbs

I am trying to implement bread crumb navigation. I have a string array in the C# code like this:

```
    public static readonly BindableProperty CurrentPathProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create<FileBrowser, string[]>(c => c.CurrentPath, null);

    public string[] CurrentPath
    {
        get { return GetValue(CurrentPathProperty) as string[]; }
        set { SetValue(CurrentPathProperty, value); }
    }
```

What would be the correct way to bind to the property in XAML (display the bread crumbs and update CurrentPath when one of them is tapped)? I've tried googling `ListView`s and `x:Array` but don't see a straightforward way to do this. I know I need a `PropertyChanged` event handler but it's not clear to me what needs to happen on the XAML side or what the handler would look like.

Comment: Can you provide the XAML you are using?

Comment: Why is your property a BindableProperty ? your property is likely the **Source** of a Binding, not the **Target**

Comment: I actually needed it to update bidirectionally - the user can navigate within the file browser control which would update the current path, or they could click on bread crumbs in the current path to update the file browser control. I ended up dynamically inserting labels from the code into a stack layout, and then hooking up a tap gesture in the property changed event handler to update the file browser control.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your control to update itself when items are added to your array, you should use something implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged`, like `ObservableCollection` instead of an array.

With that as source, you can bind it to the `ItemSource` of a `ListView`; the `ListView` being the only Xamarin.Forms controls that supports DataTemplating out of the box.

Anything more complex require defining your own control, inheriting e.g. from `StackLayout` or any other `Layout`, and handle creating a `Label` for each of the string added to your array.